# Два <select>-а и массив со значенями Empty, NotEmpty, надо менять параметры второго select-a

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Есть 2 `<select>` и массив со значениями `0` и `1` (Нарисована таблица со значениями, и в массиве хранится заполнена ли ячейка или нет)
В первом `<select>` есть значения: "В очереди", "На тесте", "Выполнено", во втором `<select>` есть значения от `1` до `9`.
Я знаю какие ячейки свободны благодаря моему массиву, и мне нужно знать, можно ли как-нибудь узнать на какое значение в первом `<select>` я нажал или какое значение выбрано, и по нему уже изменить параметры второго `<select>` (Например, если там занято, то сделать `disabled` или покрасить `background` `color` в красный цвет, если не занято, то пусть остается таким же по дефолту)

```
<select size="5" style="margin-left: 1.5px; font-size: 2px; width: 21.5px; overflow: hidden;" name="first" required>
                                            <option value="1">В очереди</option>
                                            <option value="2">В работе</option>
                                            <option value="3">На тесте</option>
                                            <option value="4">Выполнено</option>
                                            <option value="5">На сопровождении</option>
                                        </select>
                                            <%--<div class="ui-select">--%>
                                            <select size="9" style="font-size: 2px; width: 7px; overflow: hidden;" name="second" required>
                                            <%
                                                for(int j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
                                            %>
                                                <option><%=j%></option>
                                                <%
                                                }
                                                %>
                                            </select>
```

Вообщем у меня 5(сопвр, выполнено, на тесте) x 9 таблица(1 - 9 ячейки), и я храню в массиве 45 элементов (от таблицы 5х9) 0 и 1 (пустая ячейка или нет) Так вот, стоят у меня два select подряд, но второй должен зависеть строго от первого(или точнее, свободна ли ячейка или нет)

Comment: Если приведете пример html и массивы, которые вам доступны - будет намного понятнее, чем строка текста

Comment: Добавил комментарии, надеюсь стало немного понятнее

Comment: То есть задача: при определенных значениях первого селекта стилизовать второй?

Comment: Да, всё так как вы сказали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрим значение селекта и добавляем нужные стили для второго

Вызываем функцию при загрузке страницы и при смене значения первого селекта

```
handleSelect();

$(document).on('change', 'select[name=first]', function(){
    handleSelect();
});

function handleSelect() {
    var value = $('select[name=first]').val(),
        second = $('select[name=second]');
  switch(value) {
    case '1':
        second.attr('style', 'background: green');
        break;
    case '2':
        second.attr('style', 'background: yellow');
        break;
    case '3':
        second.attr('style', 'background: red');
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Не подскажешь, как реализовать это в коде? 
Функцию я вынесу за <script> function handleSelect() {} </script>, handleSelect();

$(document).on('change', 'select[name=first]', function(){
    handleSelect();
}); а вот это как использовать, как привязать к селекту?

Comment: @Timka, Туда же, рядом с функцией, когда страница загрузится код выполнится и произойдет привязка к событию

Comment: @Timka, Только я тут JQuery использовал, если у тебя не подключена, надо будет найти как сделать нативно